# How to get mouse movement and mouse position in VIM?

Tags: vim

I am thinking about a plugin to show and hide nerdtree automatically. The nerdtree is shown when mouse is in the first 5 columns, and hide when the mouse is out of the first 10 columns.  However, I cannot find the mouse movement events and mouse position api in the vim.  Is there a method to get mouse movement in vim or vim-python?

PS:  I mean the mouse movement instead of the cursor movement.  To toggle NerdTree by cursor position I think it is not a good idea.

Comment: IMHO, Vim would be more powerful if you just use your keyboard without mouse at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook into **mouse clicks** via `:nnoremap <LeftMouse> ...`, but as that is supposed to set the current cursor position, it would be more consistent to also hook into equivalent cursor position changes via the keyboard. But having a NerdTree side panel slide in and out based on the cursor position in the buffer feels very odd... What I'm trying to say is: This is a bad approach for Vim.

Vim (even graphical GVIM) is a text editor with cell addressing. In the terminal, there's no way to get the current mouse position (without clicking); it's not part of the protocol: The mouse didn't exist when terminals were invented; and its support was grafted on much later. Now, GVIM could theoretically implement this, but it chooses to remain as close to the terminal as possible (cp. `:help design-not`).

#### alternative approaches

In Vim, everything is key-based, and the different modes make key mappings short, memorable, and often without modifier keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>. I would map either an (unused) function key (`<F3>`), or combo (`<Leader>t`):

```
:nnoremap <Leader>t :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot~ I tried to figure out other ways of toggling the NerdTree but I finally final bind it with Ctrl-n is, indeed, a good idea.